# Strategy to implement paid API in the mobile application

Tags: json, api, rest, long-polling

I'm developing an app that shows the score of sports-related games in real-time. I'm using a paid API that has limited no. of requests and to show the score in real-time, I'm using a short polling technique (hit the API after every 2-3 seconds to see if any change happens in the score)

If I directly place that API url in the application, then every application user would be directly hitting an API. Assuming 10 users are using an application, then 10 API calls would be deducted after specified time interval (2-3 seconds), right?

So what should be the strategy (better way or approach) to do this thing to prevent multiple API calls?

What I could come up with his store the API JSON response in the MYSQL database. This way, I would be serving the data to application users through the database (this way, users would hit the database, not an actual API) Is it the correct way to do it?

1. Store the API JSON response into the MYSQL database
2. Then reconvert the MySQL database into the JSON format
3. and then the application users would be polling the database JSON response

I don't know if this is the correct way to do it! That's why posted this question

Thank you